Persisting log-in session in angular using jwt
I am trying to create a login service that will keep track of whether a user is logged in or not. I have implemented a server which uses JWT's and works correctly. I am now trying use my auth service/user service to drive aspects of the UI e.g show navigation menu items if the user is logged in or not. The issue I face is when the app is refreshed or rebuilt, it doesn't seem to react to existing tokens stored in localstorage(this is a temporary solution whilst i build by app)
auth/user service
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  public token?: Observable<UserToken>;
  public isLoggedIn = (): Observable<boolean> =>
    this.loggedInSubject.asObservable();

  private loggedInSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private tokenSubject?: BehaviorSubject<UserToken>;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

    this.tokenSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserToken>({
      token: storedToken || '',
    });
    this.token = this.tokenSubject?.asObservable();
  }

  login(user: Login): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/login`, user).pipe(
      map((token: any) => {
        this.saveToken(token);
        this.loggedInSubject.next(true);
        this.router.navigate(['/test']);

        return token;
      })
    );
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.tokenSubject?.next({ token: '' });
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  register(user: SignUp): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/register`, user).pipe(
      map((token: any) => {
        this.saveToken(token);
        return token;
      })
    );
  }
  public get tokenValue(): UserToken {
    return this.tokenSubject?.value ?? { token: '' };
  }

  private saveToken(token: UserToken) {
    console.log('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', token.token);
    this.tokenSubject?.next(token);
  }
}

From this service - I use the
  public isLoggedIn = (): Observable<boolean> =>
    this.loggedInSubject.asObservable();

in my component e.g the nav component
  @if(!(isLoggedIn$ | async) ){
  <li routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="['active']">
    <a>Sign Up</a>
  </li>
  <li routerLink="/login"><a>Login</a></li>
  } @else {
  <li routerLink="/create-match"><a>Create Match</a></li>
  <li (click)="logout()"><a>Log out</a></li>
  }

I believe the issue may be to do with the observable omits a false initially without checking the localstorage. How can i achieve this?


localStorage.setItem('token', token.token);


I see you are saving the .token but everywhere else you give the whole object.
Maybe thats the problem?
